# ms-dos command shell sort returns "Input file specified two times."

Tags: shell, sorting

I am trying to sort a .txt file by column 151 and output it to a new .txt file. I enter the code in the shell window at the DOS prompt "sort /+151 C:\Users\Drafter 1\Index1.txt /O C:\Users\Drafter 1\Index2.txt" and the return is "Input file specified two times." It has been a few years since I had to do this, but have never had a problem until now. I can't help but feel I have overlooked something obvious.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the file names if they contain spaces. Correct would be:

```
sort /+151 "C:\Users\Drafter 1\Index1.txt" /O "C:\Users\Drafter 1\Index2.txt"
```